# How can i create an Arrow with an editable label (for connecting two nodes)?

Tags: javafx, arrows

I am using the class [`Arrow`](https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/graph-editor/blob/master/api/src/main/java/de/tesis/dynaware/grapheditor/utils/Arrow.java) from this project on github : https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/graph-editor

```
    public Arrow() {

        line.getStyleClass().add(STYLE_CLASS_LINE);
        head.getStyleClass().add(STYLE_CLASS_HEAD);

      */
    public Arrow() {

        line.getStyleClass().add(STYLE_CLASS_LINE);
        head.getStyleClass().add(STYLE_CLASS_HEAD);
        arrowText.getStyleClass().add(textArrow);  

        Group n=new Group(hb,line,head);

        hb.getChildren().add(t);

    }
}
```

And I want to create `Arrow` with editable label. But I don't know how to process. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Just add a `TextField` (or a `Label` that is replaced by a `TextField` when the appropriate user interaction occurs). What exactly is the problem? Also I wonder why the `draw()` method is `public`. This could be done in the setter methods as well (or in [`layout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layout--), if doing this multiple times should be prevented). Also all those properties would be implemented as properties, if this was a class from the javafx API...

Comment: My Classe Arrow extends a Pane, and when i try to add a TextField or a label to the constructor, i got this error message : "TextField cannot be convert to Node"

Comment: Are you sure you use the correct `TextField` class? You can see the `Node` class in the class hierarchy here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html

Comment: You were right..it works perfectly..thank u fabian